# Inverted colors when using android emulator on virtual machine

Tags: android, qt, android-emulator, virtual-machine, qemu

When I use the Android emulator on a remote virtual machine, the colors become inverted

[image]

and the console on which the emulator is running shows the following errors:

```
emulator -avd nexus_5x_v711_x86_64 -accel on
QXcbConnection: Failed to initialize XRandr
Qt: XKEYBOARD extension not present on the X server.
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x38d to 0x0
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x38d to 0x0
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x38d to 0x0
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x38d to 0x0
Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:
 - Start Android Studio
 - Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
 - Click "SDK Tools" tab
 - Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
 - Click "OK"

qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to get MSR 0x38d
Falling back to using screens root_visual.
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QWidget::render: Cannot render with an inactive painter
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
```

I'm quite desperate. Could someone please help me with it?
If I take a screenshot directly using the emulator function, the screenshot saves with the normal color balance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install (or at least select) whatever driver package X11 needs to run on the hypervisor that you use. On VMware it’d Be VMware-tools; on qemu — I’m not sure. Basically, the guest X server is not configured properly to run on top of the hypervisor’s emulated video device.